# How to get value of a ListView item, populated through FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a `ListView` that I populate using the `FirebaseListAdapter`. Now I want the `OnItemClickListener` to show the value of the item clicked (the text displayed on the item) in a `Toast`.

```
ListView listView;
ListAdapter listAdapter;

mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<firebase root ref>/posts");
mFirebaseQuery = mFirebaseRef.orderByChild("author_id").equalTo(id); //`id` is a variable defined earlier

listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Post>(this, Post.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_, mFirebaseQuery) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, Post post) {
        String postTopic = post.getTopic();

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(postTopic);
    }
};

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.postsList);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String topic = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Item Value: "+topic, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Instead of returning the text displayed on the item (as is in the case an `ArrayAdapter` is used), `String.valueOf` returns some reference to the model class I use - `Post.class`.
The output is something like this: `com.example.android.model.Post@a1e1874`

Can anybody tell me how to get the value of the list item in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AdapterView.getItemAtPosition()` returns a `Post` object, so:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Post post = (Post)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    String topic = post.getTopic();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Item Value: "+topic, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```